# Signalr - endless $.connection.hub.disconnected event?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, .net-4.6

I'm using Signalr 2.2.1 with a successful websocket connection.

[image]

Here are the events for different states : ( simplified for brevity)

```
var hub = $.connection.moveShapeHub;


$.connection.hub.start().done(function ()
{
    console.log("hub started successfully");

}).fail(function () { console.log('Could not Connect!'); });


$.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
{
    $.connection.hub.start();
    console.log('Connection disconnected')
});
```

My app is working fine as expected.

But look what happen  when I *disable* the network card *( I access my computer not via localhost but via dynamic dns which goes to the world and then comes back to my computer)*

At first you can see websocket connection error (I see it multiple times)

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://xxxxxx.ddns.net/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&messageId=d-C68A95E5-g%2C1&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=%2FDJL8eAtVtSA3XKeap4Js3IrbkCm56C%2FWKCQtApGiMroWAgnzNoRHmJ0Y2LpIdWWWL%2BfY3dXvJqYHFfby1XYii0ibPpKM55PQuZyf9aH4k9JHIT79lWoMWBasIpa9Gjk&connectionData=%5B%5D&tid=2'
>   f**ailed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED**

And then you see **endless calls**(!!!) to the negotiate

> http://xxxx.ddns.net/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=%2FDJL8eAtVtSA3XKeap4Js3IrbkCm56C%2FWKCQtApGiMroWAgnzNoRHmJ0Y2LpIdWWWL%2BfY3dXvJqYHFfby1XYii0ibPpKM55PQuZyf9aH4k9JHIT79lWoMWBasIpa9Gjk&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22moveshapehub%22%7D%5D&_=1485811277855

Wait **~15** seconds to see the endless loop :

[image]

**Question**

How can I fix those endless calls ? Or alternatvly - increase delay in those "negotiate calls"  -say every 2 seconds ( instead of blazing fast endlessly 0.1 seconds)

**Edit**

I've changed this code :

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
    {
        $.connection.hub.start();
        console.log('Connection disconnected')
    });
```

to this  (remove hub start):

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function ()
    {
             console.log('Connection disconnected')
    });
```

And now I see only this message :

[image]

But now I'm losing all the basic idea of "trying restart connecting" in case of disconnect. So I ask again is there any reasonable solution or at least trying "restart the connection every 2 seconds" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`negotiate` is the first request a SignalR client sends to establish a connection. You are trying to start the connection as soon as it gets disconnected in the `disconnected` event handler. Because the network is down `negotiate` fails and the `disconnected` event is invoked and you try to start the connection again. 
The [documentation](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#continuousreconnect) shows how to do it with the timeout:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

Comment: I thought about setTimeout , but something in my head told me that if i'm in the disconnected function  -  it's OK trying doing it again.Of course - setTimeout is the answer and I've missed that. thank you.

Comment: Because there is no network the client goes immediately from the disconnected to connecting and then the disconnected state and each time the state changes a corresponding event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all issues of SR connections is check and persist connection status on each server request. I have created a method that takes the proxy method as a parameter and fires the proxy method after establishing the hub connection is available.

call the method using SR_Connection.execute.

When it has established the connection is commits the execution of the request.

```
function cancel(){
    SR_Connection.execute('SRProxy.server.Cancel', uniqueID);
}

var SR_Connection = (function () {
    //Start of the Return Statement
    return {
        execute: function (method, params) {
            if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    SR_Connection.commit(method, params);
                });
            }
            else {
                SR_Connection.commit(method, params);
            }
        },
        commit: function (method, params) {
            var namespaces = method.split("."),
                context;

            if (typeof (window) == "undefined") {
                context = global;
            } else {
                context = window;
            }

            var functionToExecute = namespaces.pop();

            for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
                context = context[namespaces[i]];
            }

            context[functionToExecute](params);
        }
    };//End of the Return Statement
})();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community